# Como pasar el valor de un SELECT a una misma pagina

Tags: php, html

estoy pasando variables de un select; mediante onchange, pero las variables se pasan de una pagina a otra. este es mi html y estoy en la pagina ejm.php:

```
<body>
<select name="miselector" id="miselector" onchange="enviar_valores(this.value);">
   <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
   <option value="coches">Coches</option>
   <option value="casas">Casas</option>
</select>

<script>

    function enviar_valores(valor){
    //Pasa los parámetros a la pagina buscar
    location.href='buscar.php?valor=' + valor;
     }

</script>
</body>
```

entonces aca toma la variable y lo pasa a la pagina buscar.php:

```
<?php 


   $valor=$_GET['valor'];

   echo $valor;

 ?>
```

pero lo que busco es que las variables se pasen en la misma pagina, se podra realizar eso?

Comment: Probaste colocando en el `location.href` la ruta de la misma pagina donde quieres el dato? en este caso `ejm.php`

Comment: Podrías especificar dónde lo quieres pasar (aunque se trate de la misma página): en otra parte del código, en otra variable para procesar, etc...?

Comment: en un php que se encuentre en la misma pagina,osea en el body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso, para acceder al valor de la variable desde php (se ejecuta en el servidor) es necesario hacer un submit del formulario donde capturas ese valor. Por ejemplo:

archivo "a.php":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="a.php">
 <select name="miselector" id="miselector" onchange="this.form.submit()">
 <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
 <option value="coches">Coches</option>
 <option value="casas">Casas</option>
</form>

///Lectura de la variable "en la misma página" desde php

<?php
echo "Select: ".$_GET["miselector"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

De todas formas, esta forma de manejar los datos no es la más apropiada. Te recomiendo estructurar mejor tu código, para separar las ejecuciones y así tener un mejor control del flujo de tu aplicación.

Comment: y como haria para pasar un select pero con onchange, osea sin la necesidad de un boton

Comment: seteas el onchange del select como onchange="this.form.submit()", que sería la misma acción que el botón, sólo que se ejecuta cuando cambia el contenido del select.

Comment: Una consulta, y habra alguna manera de pasar con AJAX en una misma pagina? es que seria genial que no se cargue la pagina... se podra?

Comment: Por supuesto que sí, podés leer esta pregunta que seguro te sirve para empezar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20351160/3239070. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza **buscar.php** por **ejm.php**

```
location.href='ejm.php?valor=' + valor;
```